# Java AWT BorderLayout() can crash libGLX_mesa.so.0 in Ubuntu Linux ver 18.04.1 - how to fix?

Tags: virtualbox, java, opengl, mesa

I have a large Java application that includes many commands such as
new `JPanel(new BorderLayout())`
`this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`
but not all of them seem to cause the crashing. I can prevent crashing by
removing `"new BorderLayout()"` in some places.
I am moving this Java application that works on MS-Windows to Ubuntu and this
is a big show-stopping problem, preventing needed panes from being displayed in
the GUI. I'm running Ubuntu in a VirtualBox on a Windows 10 PC.

I am using NetBeans 8.2 and Java 8. Here is some of the output pane output:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3918aba440, pid=2616, tid=0x00007f38ba2aa700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b10) (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libGLX_mesa.so.0+0x45440]
```

My version of libGLX_mesa.so comes from here:

```
 libglx-mesa0_19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb
I also tried
 libglx-mesa0_19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.1_amd64.deb
 libglx-mesa0_18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb
 libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.10.2_amd64.deb
```

Here are the imports in one of the source code files that I am working with:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;
import shooter.controller.MsgHandler;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Doing:
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
I get:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.8

Edit:
A coworker found that the Mesa 3D Graphics Library is currently supported for
devices designed by Intel, AMD, NVIDIA, Qualcomm, Broadcom, Vivante, plus the
VMware and VirGL virtual GPUs. We were trying to use this library in Ubuntu
Linux on a VirtualBox, which does not support the Mesa 3D Graphics Library yet.
He installed our Java program on Ubuntu Linux installed natively on a PC and
found that libGLX_mesa.so.0 does not crash there. (Today is Fri Dec 13, 2019)

We don't need to change anything about the AWT BorderLayout class.